# What are the common tricks in eclipse when working with jsp files?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I looked through this list of [“Hidden” features/tricks for Eclipse?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-tricks-for-eclipse), but it doesn't have anything for web-developement (jsp). A very useful list of tricks for a general eclipse user!

I work with jsp pages in [Eclipse Ganymede](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), and I would like to find out a list of shortcuts commonly used to facilitate development.  I always seem to struggle with the following, among other issues:

- always traverse a directory tree to find a file (no Ctrl-shift-t just like java classes)
- search is always ends up with either ctrl-f or searching the entire project

I would appreciate if you guys list tricks for eclipse, specifically for web-development (jsp/tomcat)

**I am a noob, so don't hesitate to list anything even if you think it is TOO NOOB!!!**

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

my favorite:

ctrl + shift + r will open a resource dialog like the type dialog

Refer [30 Useful Eclipse Keyboard Shortcuts for Java Programmers](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/eclipse-tutorial-most-useful-eclipse.html) for more.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, be certain you use the Java EE version of Eclipse.

---

Edit:

Use Ctrl-Shift-R to locate a given resource (also known as "file").

You can use F3 on java identifiers in <%...%> to go to their definition.

The best tip I can give you is to learn JSF or similar so your JSP files only contain tags, and not java snippets.

Answer (score 1):

I use the MyEclipse plugin.  I have been very happy with it and it has a lot of jsp support.

[MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Get the [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) plugin. I think it's included by default in the Jave EE edition of Eclipse, but you can also install it separately. To see if it's installed in your Eclipse, open the Help|About screen and look for a "WTP" icon.

It doesn't provide any web-specific shortcuts, but it will give you syntax highlighting and some auto-completion for HTML and CSS files, and for JSP files, enable many of the navigation features that you're used to from Java editing. (Such as Ctrl+Space to import a class and F3 to see its definition.)

Regardless of whether you have WTP installed or not:

- Use Ctrl+Shift+R to open files; this works much like Ctrl+Shift+T for opening classes.
- Use Ctrl+H to search the whole of your project, or parts of it. If you pick the "File search" tab, you can specify file patterns (such as `*.jsp`) to search in. If you click on a folder in the Package Explorer, you can select "Selected resources" from the "Scope" box to search only in that folder (and its sub-folders).