# War file deployment

Tags: eclipse, jsp, encoding, weblogic, war

I wrote a jsp application, and if I generate a war file with eclipse in windows XP, language: tradition Chinese. and deploy to weblogic, 
it will have such problem:

```
inputAdministrator.jsp:251:11: This type name is ambiguous because it matches more than one '*'-import, including 'java.io.*' and 'admin.iguard.businessObject.*'.
                                        DataInput d = (DataInput) dataInput;
                                                                                ^-------^
inputAdministrator.jsp:252:29: Type java.io.DataInput contains no methods named getDept1.
                                            String dept1 = d.getDept1();
                                                                                                         ^------^
inputAdministrator.jsp:253:26: No match was found for method trim() in type <error>.
                                            String emp2 = d.getEmp2().trim();
                                                                                                      ^----------------^
inputAdministrator.jsp:253:28: Type java.io.DataInput contains no methods named getEmp2.
                                            String emp2 = d.getEmp2().trim();
                                                                                                        ^-----^
inputAdministrator.jsp:254:29: Type java.io.DataInput contains no methods named getDept2.
                                            String dept2 = d.getDept2();
                                                                                                         ^------^
inputAdministrator.jsp:255:33: Type java.io.DataInput contains no methods named getDept_code.
                                            String dept_code = d.getDept_code();
                                                                                                             ^----------^
inputAdministrator.jsp:256:32: Type java.io.DataInput contains no methods named getStaff_no.
                                            String staff_no = d.getStaff_no();
                                                                                                            ^---------^
inputAdministrator.jsp:257:32: Type java.io.DataInput contains no methods named getEmp2_por.
                                            String emp2_por = d.getEmp2_por();
                                                                                                            ^---------^
```

if I generate the war file in windows xp, simplize Chinese, and deploy to weblogic, everything will be OK.

I don't know how the "text file encoding" setting will affect the generated war file, 
how can i make sure that all this things are in sync.

Any one have better solution?
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: chk the workspace text encoding in eclipse IDE in both J2EE exports to make sure its indeed a Text encoding issue? It defaults to (cp1532)

Comment: yeah, export the war in different environment will cause the error, through if i don't use import but hard code the whole class name in the jsp will solve the problem, but i really want to know the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you check it? does text encoding changes in both the j2ee exports as a WAR file?

`windows-->preferences-->General-->workspace-->textfileencoding`?

it defaults to **cp1532**

what is the value of textfileencoding variable set in **simplize Chinese** as compared to **tradition Chinese** ??

Comment: MS950  -tranditional
big5   -simplize

Comment: this is the issue,>>how can i make sure that all this things are in sync.<<

make sure that both use the same text-encoding, when you deploy =]

Answer (score 0):

May be the "text file encoding" triggers some kind of recompilation which makes that issue visible.

In any case, could you try first to disambiguate the DataInput usage, by:

- adding for example "`java.io.`"(in front of `DataInput`) everywhere in that source where it is actually a `java.io` case (leaving a simple DataInput for businessObject usages)
- not using import `java.io.*` (but using [<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for reorganizing the imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-tricks-for-eclipse/54920#54920))

would that solve the problem, whatever the "text file encoding" is?

Comment: their is a setting in eclipse named "text file encoding".