# Less known but useful features in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have been using Eclipse for a long time, the feature that is less known but very useful is the Scrapbook Page, that allows you to execute sections of the Java code without having them to be complete classes. For example, if I need to execute this simple for-loop I can do this by creating a scrap page (File->New->Other->Scrapbook Page) and then typing the following and they pressing the "Execute the Selected Text" or Ctrl-U will execute the code directly

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    System.out.println("Here is the scrapbook page line: " + i);
}
```

Please post other less known but useful features that are available with eclipse. I know that there are entries in SO that mention the useful shortcuts available in eclipse, however this one is about forgotten or less known features

Comment: I don't know if this question should be 1) closed because too subjective 2) marked as community wiki 3) moved to superuser...

Comment: Moved to community wiki no doubt, but nice tip, Ram

Comment: I don't see how this is different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plugin Spy (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) is certainly one not very advertised.
Yet if you have any question about "how I develop a feature X looking like the one in eclipse", it can be very useful to quickly locate the right eclipse java source which does implement that feature!

[image]
<sub>(source: [willianmitsuda.com](http://www.willianmitsuda.com/wp-content/uploads/eclipse_tips/spy_opentype.gif))</sub>

See also this [Guide to eclipse3.5](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy):

> The Plugin Spy gives you easily information about the running UI.
>   Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get information about the current running Eclipse plugin / data types / screen.
>   This way you can get immediately access to the plugin which is currently running.

[image]
<sub>(source: [vogella.de](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/images/pluginspy10.gif))</sub>

> **Eclipse 3.5 introduced the possibility to check which plugin contributed a menu**. Press "<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>" and select a menu to see who is contributing this menu

[image]
<sub>(source: [vogella.de](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/images/pluginspy20.gif))</sub>

Comment: Very interesting. But I cant manage to activate it :(. [Version: Helios Service Release 1, Build id: 20100917-0705], OSX. Anybody know how? Tried all the modifier combinations I could think of.

Comment: @JonasN try <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> to see if any shortcut exists referencing the PlugIn Spy. It depends on the context though.

Comment: Searched bindings for '[p]lug' and 'spy', found ⇧⌥F3 (Shift-Alt-F3): Show Plug-in Contributor. Not as cool though...

Comment: @JonasN is this linked to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=227949#c21 ?

Comment: I don't know. Problem seems to be I can't find any "Plugin Spy" in "Keys" preference.

Comment: @JonasN which eclipse do you have: there are many "packages" available for Helios: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php, more precisely: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/sr2 (can you check also if the issue persists with Indigo or the latest Juno?)

Comment: Aha, are you saying that the 'Spy' shortcut comes with some sort of Eclipse-developer package? That makes sense. -- Trying the Alt-Shift-F1 (Scout's salute, middle finger barely reaches F1, phew) in a Juno installation I have but don't use (Juno Release, Build id: 20120614-1722). It seems to work there, although not always, but that's probably me not understanding exactly what GUI elements that can be inspected. Anyhow, I can now find the OpenTypeSelectionDialog  that I am interested in, and perhaps find out why it's getting slow.

Comment: Oh, and the Eclipse where it seems not to work: Helios Service Release 1, Build id: 20100917-0705

Comment: @Jonas Indeed, the availability of this feature is both a question of "distro" (or "package"), and a question of context within the application.

Answer (score 1):

I like the fact, that you don't necessarily need to create a new class by using New->Class, when having the class source somewhere in the clipboard. You can simply select the destination package and paste the clipboard content.