# How to pass object from editor to property sheet in eclipse plugin development?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have an editor, this is suppose to interact with property sheet and outline views. I used Iselectionprovider interface to achieve this, but I am not able to do interaction between the editor and views.

Please give me some sample code snippets for this.

Answer (score 0):

Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> right in the middle of your Java editor.
That will display the class of that editor:[`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/javaeditor/CompilationUnitEditor.java.htm)

You will have then ton of example of listener between that editor and various other views, like that [`org.eclipse.jface.util.PropertyChangeEvent`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/util/PropertyChangeEvent.java.htm).

In short, [**Plug-in Spy**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464026/less-known-but-useful-features-in-eclipse/1464153#1464153) is your friend for this kind of code exploration.

Comment: How to use IPropertySourceProvider and IAdaptable for editors.I have got some examples for views only.Can you provide some sample code snippets for editor and properties view binding.

regards
Mathan