# Where is the "externalize strings" eclipse plug-in source code?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I need to look at "externalize strings" eclipse plug-in source code.

I have to make a modified version of that functionality and don't want to start from scratch. I try to import the plug-in using File->Import->Plug-ins and Fragments, which I think is the right way to do it, but I don't have a clue of what is the name of the plug-in, and it has not an intuitive name (or at least I have not found it) :-/

Any ideas of what is the name of the plug-in or where else can I find the source code of that specific functionality?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the **[plug-in spy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464026/less-known-but-useful-features-in-eclipse/1464153#1464153)** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) on the Externalize String Wizard.

You will see that its class is the [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.nls.**ExternalizeWizardPage**`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/refactoring/nls/ExternalizeWizardPage.java.htm), invoked by the [`**ExternalizeWizard**`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/refactoring/nls/ExternalizeWizard.java.htm) class.

If you have the classic RCP eclipse edition, the sources are included: just click on the links displayed by the plug-in Spy.
(Otherwise, all sources are available at [**kickjava.com**](http://kickjava.com), as illustrated by the two previous links on the `ExternalizeWizard`[...] classes)

Mandatory screenshot with shaky hand-drawn circles...

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20120712032638/http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/4112/externalizestringclass.png]

Comment: Thanks :-)

I've solved the problem the hard way, but this is much better. Great Info!