# Search button in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

where can i find the complete source code of search button in eclipse

Comment: Try http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t52884.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (see [Plugin Spy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464026/less-known-but-useful-features-in-eclipse/1464153#1464153)) and click on the search button.

You will get relevant classes and packages, allowing you to find [**`SearchUI`**](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/search/ui/SearchUI.java.htm) or [**`NewSearchUI`**](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/search/ui/NewSearchUI.java.htm).
Note the [**`org.eclipse.search2.internal.ui`**](http://kickjava.com/src/org.eclipse.search2.internal.ui.index.htm) contains also relevant classes.

The active contribution item identifier:

```
org.eclipse.search.OpenSearchDialogPage
```

The active contribution location URI:

```
toolbar:org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet?after=org.eclipse.search.OpenSearchDialogPage
```

The active action set identifier:

```
org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet
```

The active contribution item class:

```
OpenSearchDialogPageAction
```

The contributing plug-in:
org.eclipse.ui.workbench (3.5.0.I20090603-2000)