# Eclipse plugin that reveals the id of (workbench) parts under the mouse cursor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

As far as I remember there exists an Eclipse plugin that reveals ids of workbench parts under the mouse cursor, e.g. the id of a coolbar contribution etc. Does somebody know its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Plug-in spy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464026/less-known-but-useful-features-in-eclipse/1464153#1464153) (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) is integrated directly in Eclipse
(since [Eclipse3.4](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/spy/index.php), and for [menus since Eclipse3.5](http://scratsh.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/eclipse-3-5-plug-in-spy-and-menus/)).

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20120712032638/http://img706.i_mageshack.us/img706/4112/externalizestringclass.png]