# How do I find eclipse plugin org.eclipse.ui.console?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Seriously, its like DLL hell all over again.  I can only find ghostly references to it - but its not on my system.  Where do I go to download this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean where do you find its jar/source, you can, if you have an Eclipse RCP, use the **[Eclipse Plugin Spy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675820/eclipse-plugin-that-reveals-the-id-of-workbench-parts-under-the-mouse-cursor/2675861#2675861)** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>):

[image]

So it is in:

```
eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.console_v3.5.0.v20100104.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for.  I'm trying to install a plugin and it needs org.eclipse.ui.console.  I don't seem to have it, so where do I get it?  I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @cuvavu: can't you extract it from any Eclipse distro?

Comment: Is it a default eclipse thing?  I wonder why its not in mine then?

Comment: @cuvavu: try downloading a Eclipse RCP edition: see http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php

Comment: @VonC: Thank you. I had a different problem (I couldn't find the sources of the org.eclipse.swt plugin's jar), but found this entry and using an Eclipse RCP package helped me, because it resolves the plugin's sources automatically, in contrast to the Eclipse Java EE edition.