# How call hierarchy is implemented

Tags: java, eclipse

i just want to know how the call hierarchy is implemented in eclipse IDE ?am not able to get any good links for that. Help

Comment: Have you looked at the Eclipse source-code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start looking, with a **[Plug-In Spy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464026/less-known-but-useful-features-in-eclipse/1464153#1464153)** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) directly in the right View, the `ViewPart` which is involved:

[image: http://img163.i_mageshack.us/img163/9469/eclipsecallh.png]

You can see the sources of [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.callhierarchy.CallHierarchyViewPart` here](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/callhierarchy/CallHierarchyViewPart.java.htm)