# how to open jar selection dialog at the eclipse pulgin code

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

At Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries tab
you click Add Jars button, you will see the JAR Selection dialog.

I like to open this JAR Selection dialog on my plugin code.

How to open this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Eclipse RCP edition (which you must have since you are developing a plugin), you can use the **[Plugin Spy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464026/less-known-but-useful-features-in-eclipse/1464153#1464153)** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and see what exact class you need:

[alt text http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/2232/eclipsetreesel.png](http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/2232/eclipsetreesel.png)

It is based on  `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.FilteredElementTreeSelectionDialog` (strangely absent from the sources of [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport`](http://kickjava.com/src/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.index.htm)), derived from [`org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.ElementTreeSelectionDialog`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/dialogs/ElementTreeSelectionDialog.java.htm).

If you want to see how it is opened, you need to have a look to the global window opening that dialog:

[alt text http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/1903/eclipselibclass.png](http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/1903/eclipselibclass.png)

It is the [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.preferences.BuildPathsPropertyPage`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/preferences/BuildPathsPropertyPage.java.htm), from which you can infer the various action classes associated with the button and see how it works.

Comment: Thanks, VonC. Your answer is perfect!!