# does netbeans or eclipse have any navigation plugins?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

Does either netbeans or eclipse have any plugins where you can quickly navigate the project?

I want something like intelliJ's navigation options, like where you just presss control-N and simply type the filename you want to jump to, or class name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Eclipse, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is search by type. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is find by file.

Consider reading these questions as well, [keyboard shortcuts in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98220) and [hidden featuers of eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886)

Answer (score 3):

It varies slightly depending on which version of NB you're running. In NB 6.8 there are these bindings (among others):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> - Go To File (prompt for file name)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> - Go To Type (under the cursor)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> - Go To Symbol (prompt for symbol name)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - Go To Declaration (of symbol under cursor)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - Go To Source (of method under cursor)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> - Go To Super implementation  (of method under cursor)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the open type and open resources dialogs [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231090/does-netbeans-or-eclipse-have-any-navigation-plugins/2231207#2231207) by basszero, I find quick access (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>) very useful: it's just like the above, but for all other Eclipse elements (views, editors, preferences, menu items, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take your navigational skills to the next level, check out [nWire](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/) (for [Java](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-java)/[PHP](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-php)). It is an innovative tool which presents all your code associations in one dynamic view. It's like having all the above mentioned tools in one place, and much more.