# Hidden Features IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

Just another Hidden features and tips and tricks `WIKI`.

After seeing the hidden features of eclipse, java, spring framework I thought we need to have a list of the features, TIPS for IntelliJ too which is the best and the Intelligent IDE available for java.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I love syntax-aware selection. Control + W.

When I'm forced to work with other IDEs, that key sequence usually causes files to close. It's a nasty negative feedback loop.

Comment: You sure that isn't a positive feedback loop? After all, it causes you to stop using those *other* IDEs. :P

Comment: For people with other keymaps: this command is called "Select Word at Caret" and "Unselect Word at Caret". I prefer the binding that the OS X keymap has, which is Alt+Up and Alt+Down

Comment: It's a brilliant feature for sure! This is my productivity guide for PHPStorm, another JetBrains IDEA IDE:
http://i.imgur.com/2bloY7k.png

Comment: Very nice feature certainly but why did they take Control + W? This is indeed a very common shortcut (also in the browser you are reading this in) to close tabs. It's one of the first shortcuts I modified.

Comment: The other negative/positive feedback loop is **CTRL + Y**: it will delete a line in IntelliJ while it will _redo_ in most of other IDE and editors. Sometimes it's destuctive.

Answer (score 66):

`Help -> Productivity Guide`: See all the fun you've been missing out.

Comment: The plugin "mouse feed" (showing the correspondive shortcut on mouse triggered actions if a shortcut is defined) was like the very next i discovered right after the productivity guide.

Comment: I think it's called [Key Promoter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1003) now.

Answer (score 18):

`Shift-F7` (Smart Step Into) is a useful debugging feature that I haven't seen with other IDE's.  I also like `CTRL-J` to pull up Live Templates, and (unrelated) `CTRL-SHIFT-J` to merge the next line with this one.

**Update**

Got a few more:

- `Ctrl-Alt-F7` to show usages in a pop-up list
- Call Hierarchy is like a more through "find usages" and shows a tree that traces method calls leading to the current code

I've got a few extra mouse buttons, so I have bound each of these to the buttons for fast access.

Comment: what does smart step into do that is different ?

Comment: If the line that you're on has more than one function call in it, a list will pop up asking you which one you want to step into

Comment: To be fair, netbeans support Shift-F7 as well.

Answer (score 12):

**Shift Control Space**

I love [Shift + Control + Space](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/tips/#tips_code_completion) for code completion, it is not a secret thought. You can use it everywhere - in a Spring configuration file, at the right side of an attribution, to complete a method call, to pass a parameter.

The nice thing about it is that if you have a parameter of type "X" inside an object "y", when you press Shift + Control + Space **twice**, it will actually display "y.X" as one of the possible options. I guess I could classify that as a secret :-).

Other shortcuts that I use often are Shift + Insert to generate code (such as equals and hashcode, or a constructor to initialize my final variables), Ctrl + I and Ctrl + O to implement/ override methods, Alt + Enter to fix a compilation error/ warning (a code inspection suggestion).

Answer (score 12):

```
CTRL+ALT+V - For variable extraction

CTRL+ALT+M - For method extraction
```

I use the above shortcuts very frequently.

Comment: CTRL + ALT + C - extract constant and CTRL+ ALT + F for field

Answer (score 10):

The one I very frequently see under utilised is `Crtl-Alt-F7` (⌘⌥-F7 in OS X), which is *show usages*. Much faster than "find usages". Both are indispensable for understanding code and how it is used.

Another one hidden away is *column mode*, which allows you to highlight and even replace code vertically. The shortcut for this is `Ctrl-Shift-Insert` (⌘⇧* in OS X).

Comment: Column mode also works with alt+click+drag. A+, would highlight with again.

Comment: you can also use column select mode with middle click+drag

Answer (score 9):

What about starting with the Intellij version of the most voted response on the [Hidden features of Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse) post? =)

> Don't forget Ctrl+Shift+**A**, which
>   displays a list of all the keyboard
>   shortcut combinations (just in case
>   you forget any of those listed here).

also:

I also suggest to print out the official: Intellij IDEA 9 Default Keymap: [WINDOWS-LINUX](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf), [OS X](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_mac.pdf), [OS X 10.5+](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA9_ReferenceCard_Mac10_5.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

the iteration based live templates seem to save more typing than any other feature, my own templates which I use frequently:

```
private final org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger($CLASS_NAME$.class);
```

(add optional `static` keyword after `private` [according to taste](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#declared_static)) where the variable CLASS_NAME is defined to have the expression `className()` and check "Skip if defined", together with

```
logger.debug("$END$");
```

Answer (score 6):

[Closure Folding](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/03/closure-folding-in-intellij-idea-9-maia/) makes Java programming slightly more tolerable after writing Scala.

Answer (score 1):

From persistence tool Window you can see the diagram of your database structure by clicking `Open ER Diagram` very useful tool