# Eclipse Top Plugins to get for a Visual Studio Developer

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, plugins

I live in Visual Studio with Resharper.

What free plug ins should I get for Eclipse to get me to the same level as I am used to in VS with Resharper.

I have found Eclipse to have many of the Resharper features built in, but don't want to be missing great productivity tools.

Comment: Do you have any specific features you're looking for?

Comment: Refactoring tools, though Eclipse seems fairly good as is, and tools to debug/visualize better.

Comment: I think it is bad form to mark the correct answer as your own. In the event that your own answer gets upvoted then it might be reasonable, but your answer doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse indeed already ships with decent builtin refactoring and static code analysis capabilities. However, there are several plugins available which improves static code analysis, the popular ones being [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) and [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/). They will report about potential programming bugs. Further there's also a static code style checker plugin [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) which will report about potential programming style flaws which may not necessarily lead to runtime errors, but rather to maintainability problems.

#### Related questions:

- [Recommended Eclipse plugins for source code analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730433/recommended-eclipse-plugins-for-java-source-code-analysis)
- [Generally recommended Eclipse plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826/do-you-have-any-recommended-plugins-for-eclipse)
- [Hidden features of Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse)