# Hidden features of Vim

Tags: vim, vi

Over the years, I thought I'm a Vim master! Recently I visited a real Vim master! oops! My knowledge is awfully superficial!

For example I didn't know it's possible to add a `\c` to make search case insensitive. (instead of `:set ignorecase`)

I clearly remember when how I'm surprised when I found [SuperTab](http://blog.dispatched.ch/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/omnicompletion.png) or [TagList](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/images/taglist_php.gif) plugins first time. Vim's official site says "Vim isn't an editor designed to hold its users' hands. It is a tool, the use of which must be learned.", so naturally it should have many undiscovered features.

So I'm asking, what are your favorite features of Vim? What are things you can do with it that you can't or are more difficult in the other editors?

Of course there's some same topics about other editors:

- [Hidden Features of Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886)
- [Hidden Features of TextPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605439)

Comment: See [Useful Vim features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735/useful-vim-features)

Comment: This should be community wiki. (The Eclipse and TextPad questions are as well.)

Comment: constantly read and use vim, then you can surprise many people. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/vim-editor-tutorial/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What feature is missing or hidden in Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255783/what-feature-is-missing-or-hidden-in-vim)

Answer (score 8):

About the "hidden" part... Try these:

```
:help 42

:help!
```

:o)

Comment: Cool!! That last one - what did it do exactly, looks like it just gave me a blank file named ")"?

Comment: @rascher: I think the last one isn't a vim command, just a smiley in this post. (look how it is not formatted the same as the first two)

Comment: Yes of course, Sergio is right about that, that's supposed to be a smiley. Sorry for the confusion :o)

Answer (score 6):

It took me a few years before I learned about text objects

```
:help text-object
:nmap cw ciw
:nmap cW ciW
```

Also nice are `ci"` and `ci` (when I want to change a string or function args).

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a hidden feature but it's a little known feature.
If you type :X then you can encrypt your file with a password.

Comment: How do you turn off the encryption of a file?

Comment: @QuintenCabo You use `:X` again with no password and then save the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the correctness of the text using line:

```
:set spell
```