# What simple Eclipse tricks do you know?

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hidden features of Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse)

I've just discovered that if you type sysout then hold ctrl and press space it changes to System.out.println()

Answer (score 0):

you can also indent the code properly.

select the code you want to format and press ctrl +shift+ 'F'

this will indent your data properly.