# How do i use eclipse efficiently by making maximum use of keyboard

Tags: eclipse

I mean to say which and all shortcuts from key board is available while working on eclipse?

like how `Ctrl+F11` is for run project like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Effective Eclipse: Shortcut keys](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key)
- [Useful Eclipse Shortcut Keys](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-code-snippets-tutorials/19-useful-eclipse-shortcut-keys.html)
- [10 Eclipse Navigation Shortcuts Every Java Programmer Should Know](http://rayfd.wordpress.com/2007/05/20/10-eclipse-navigation-shortcuts-every-java-programmer-should-know/)

You can define your own:

- [FAQ How do I provide a keyboard shortcut for my action?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F)

Provider by [MatrixFrog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65977/matrixfrog) in comments below:

- [Hidden features of Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse)

Comment: You may also enjoy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Press `ctrl + shift + l` it will open shortcut key menu.

Note:- 
Beside this also some other short cut will available. If you tell us functionality you wanna access we can tell you the short cut for it.