# What are some useful shortcuts in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

What are some useful shortcuts in Eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hidden features of Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse)

Comment: too open of a question. please read the faq. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: sorry about the mistake guys.

Answer (score 1):

I love editing ones.

`Ctrl + Shift + M` = Add import
`Ctrl + Shift + F` = Reformat ***(the best)***
`Ctrl + Shift + O` = Organize Imports
`Ctrl + /` = Comment
`Ctrl + \` = UnComment
`Ctrl + I` = Correct indentation

Also this ones handy.

`F3` = Goto declaration

A Whole List can be found here -->
[Eclipse Shortcuts](http://www.allapplabs.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm)

Comment: you can use the kbd html tag.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite: `Ctrl+2, R` to rename all instances of a variable in a class.

Answer (score 1):

Ones I use most often

Ctrl + space auto complete.

Ctrl + / to comment a line/block

sysout to expand to system.out.println();

syserr to expand to system.err.println();

F3 for go to declaration

F4 to display hierachy

and select text and press Ctrl + Arrow UP/down, try it

Answer (score 1):

Some of My favorite shortcuts :

1) ctrl + Shift + R //Open Resource

2) ctrl + Shift + / and \ //For Add Block and Remove Comment.

3) ctrl + Shift + O //For Auto import of packages.

4)ctrl + 7 //For inline comments.

5)Ctrl + Shift + F  //  Reformatting

6)ctrl + Space  //Off course for intelligence

Answer (score 1):

ctrl + shift + / to minimize all folding block.

ctrl + shift + * to expand all folding blocks.

Of course you have to have folding enabled :D

Answer (score 1):

This picture [short cut for Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu26l.jpg) will helps.It gathers most of short cuts in Eclipse in 
categories.Certainly it has what your want.