# eclipse shortcuts collection

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to start a discussion of what are some of **not widely known but very usefull** eclipse short keys you guys use day to day life.
Let me start by something,

ctr+E -> shows the current open file list in the open perspective

Any one know how to go to package declaration by restoring the current perspective (when you are in maximize mode of the perspective)?

Comment: Already asked . Did you press Ctrl+Shift+L on eclipse ?

Comment: *I would like to start a discussion*: Sorry, but this is not the site for discussions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse

Comment: Quote from the [Faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): `If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.`

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Gives List of key bindings in Eclipse .

Comment: If you're going to post a key combo, you should at least explain what it does.

Comment: Ha. I (belatedly) see what you did there.

Answer (score 0):

There are several pages with Eclipse Shortcuts Cheats

For example:

http://devcheatsheet.com/tag/eclipse/

http://www.n0sl33p.org/dev/eclipse_keys.html

The one from DZone is normally very well explained.