# Eclipse shortcut to insert variable in string literal

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

When I need to interpolate a String variable into a quoted string literal in the Eclipse java editor, I generally type "++" and eclipse usually inserts another " after the latter one, so I then have to go past it with arrow keys and then backspace to remove the duplicate, then go insert some spaces in between the "++" and type my variable name.

This seems like a lot of work. I have found [Practically Macro](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/practically-macro), but I thought there might be something built in for this situation which is very common for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most relevant built-in feature is maybe the "Pick out part of a string" quick assist:

- insert a space (or anything else) where you want to add a variable,
- select it,
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>,
- select the "Pick out part of a string" quick assist,
- insert your variable name.

Reference: "Pick out part of a string" section in [this post](http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/extract-constants-from-strings-and-numbers-with-eclipse-refactorings/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this shortcut exists, try doing **CTRL+SHIFT+L** when the string is selected.

Also there is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse) which has a whole bunch of nice keyboard shortcuts, I know it may not answer the question completely but maybe it'll get you one step closer. :)

**** Edit: In that link the "Ctrl-2 something" post looks promising.****