# Hidden keybindings (?)

Tags: eclipse, key, key-bindings, eclipse-juno

In the Eclipse Juno I cannot unbind the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, because the binded command (show properties in SVN) is working with this binding, meanwhile there is no any bind to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in the Preferences / General / Keys tab. Moreover, I unbinded all of bindings to <kbd>W</kbd>.

The problem is that the <kbd>ALTGR</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) is the '|' (pipe) character in the Hungarian keyboard layout. So, I cannot type '|' in the Eclipse.

Maybe, are there the hidden keybindings somewhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/54886/106261

Comment: This link is not answer my problem, but only discuss about Eclipse shortcuts and keybindings (which can be viewed in Preferences) In my Eclipse there is no any bindings to CTRL+ALT+W, but it do 'Show SVN Properties' instead of type '|'. That's my problem!

Answer (score 11):

I have found the resolve!
All keybindigs stored in `[your-workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi`, and I found here the CTRL+ALT+W (*I don't know why not visible in Preferences*). I changed it to any other key, or insert a `<tags>deleted</tags>` into the `bindings` tag. (I had exited from Eclipse before did it).
Once restarted the Eclipse the CTRL+ALT+W is freed.

Now the ALTGR+W types the '|'. That was my goal!

Comment: same problem... it wasn't an issue before. I don't know if it's because of system reinstallation and eclipse workspace copy.

Comment: Just checked. It's definitely because of the workspace copy. To avoid this behaviour import old projects one by one in a fresh Eclipse.

Comment: Contrary to @IBoS I just had this right after I created a fresh workspace and imported some projects. Phantom keybinding. When I copied the `workbench.xmi` from the other workspace, it was fixed. The reason is probably because Eclipse maintains this file in parallel with `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs`, so if you copy one but not the other, things go out of sync.

Comment: I had same problem with new eclipse with new workspace in which I had imported projects used within old Eclipse / workbench.