# Disable ALT bindings in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vim, binding

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. Is there a way to unbind all the default <kbd>ALT</kbd> bindings that Eclipse has? Specifically the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> which pops up the Help menu. I use vrapper inside Eclipse and I bind <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> '5h' in normal mode. In gvim I solve this by using winaltkeys=no and at the terminal there is a similar option in Preferences. In Eclipse however, I can't see a way to fix this. In General > Keys there's no <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in the list.

Comment: There's a "Keys" panel in Eclipse's option window that you can use to add/change/remove keybindings.

Comment: As I stated above, I can't find 'ALT+H' in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research here and there, I just found the answer to this seemingly-impossible-to-answer question.. It's for Eclipse Juno but should work with other versions I suppose.

> I have found the resolve! All keybindigs stored in
>   [your-workspace].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi, and I found here the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (I don't know why not visible in
>   Preferences). I changed it to any other key, or insert a
>   deleted into the bindings tag. (I had exited from Eclipse
>   before did it). Once restarted the Eclipse the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is freed.
>
> Now the <kbd>ALTGR</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> types the '|'. That was my goal!

Link of the answer:
[Hidden keybindings (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052758/hidden-keybindings)

I have been struggling with this since I got custom bindings in my vimrc, and they severely conflicted with Eclipse's hotkeys that weren't shown in Preferences > Keys.

Cheers.

Comment: This does not work - a) it has no effect on the keys and b) the file gets overwritten every time eclipse closes.

Answer (score 0):

To get characters as } or ] with AltGr key, you must search for Ctrl+Alt+Key in key bindings CTRL+SHIFT+L and unbind the key combination. Strange that Ctrl+Alt is same
as AltGr (right Alt) in the Eclipse but this method solved my problem.