# Eclipse key for "go to typed in class"

Tags: eclipse

Is there a key in Eclipse Neon.3 (Java) that allows me to type in a class name and which then takes me to that class, whichever project in my workspace contains it? Specifically, *I am not sitting in a source file with a reference to it*, but I have a case like someone emails me and says "I have a question about class StoreImportantData" and I want to be able to type that class name in and go to it without thinking about where it might be located. Various "Search" functions will work, but are very clumsy or require temporarily changing my default search settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `Ctrl+Shift+T` is bound to Open Type - should be the default, I'm pretty sure that I've not changed it.

Note: `Ctrl+Shift+L` list all key bindings, and the preferences

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys
```

lists all commands and bindings. It not only allows changing the binding, but also has a filter field that helps searching a specific functionality..

Comment: also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse