# What are the best tips & tricks you use with Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

There are a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529/useful-eclipse-features) of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse) threads here, but most of the other tips don't work on PDT so let's make this one specific to [Eclipse PDT for PHP](http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt).

I'll start (w/ credit to those that work from other the other threads):

1. CTRL-SPACE   = code completion
2. CMD-/        = auto comment
3. CMD-SHIFT-L  = key assist
4. If autocomplete isn't working right and filenames aren't expanding, right 
   click on project folder and go to php build path and add folder
5. CMD-SHIFT-t  = shows list of classnames
6. CMD-SHIFT-r  = shows list of files
7. I would say add the [Generate Getters and Setters plugin](http://pdt.plugins.e-surf.pl/) except I just did and it doesn't work for me.
8. Don't like the @author variable used by the doc block? [Change it](http://morlhon.net/blog/2005/09/07/eclipse-username/). Note the comments include the tricky way of fixing this on the Mac.

Comment: Actualy this is all not needed. Just code and be happy :) All basic features Eclipse PDT already enables. For example in `$this->` will open a window with what is availabale or insted of `$this` instance and so on. I found commenting useful ` Ctrl+Shift+/ ` and ` Ctrl+Shift+\ `.

Comment: I spent a bit of time today looking at shortcuts and boy have they been time savers. What prompted it was that I noticed the functions being expandable on the files in one project, not the other. So I debugged it. But if you prefer not to optimize your Eclipse coding experience, feel free :)

Answer (score 1):

Something that works for me very well is to customize the coloring of the syntax in the eclipse preferences. It helps me to differentiate the syntax-elements. The standard coloring often allocates the same color to several elements. I ve added a picture of my coloring to this post:

[Eclipse PHP Syntax Coloring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24evK.png)