# Eclipse - Declare variable based on return or get (Shortcut)

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, declaration, shortcut

I'm not sure how to phrase this in a search, however I was curious if there's a shortcut in eclipse to allow us to declare a variable type based on what's after the equal.

For example:

```
firstname = User.getFirstName();
```

The minute you press <kbd>enter</kbd>, it would add "String" to the beginning of the line so it becomes:

```
String firstname = User.getFirstName();
```

Or even a shortcut key would suffice.

There are times when a class name might be long, or something like: `Iterator<Entry<String, String>>` which is long enough that a shortcut or auto add would be handy.

I'm not sure if this exists though.

Thanks guys.

Comment: You can also take a look at [[hidden-features-of-eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse)] and [[useful-eclipse-features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529/useful-eclipse-features)]

Comment: @Pshemo +1 This is the best information.. Thanks for the links, helped me a lot

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I usually just write the expression:

```
User.getFirstName()
```

Then highlight it and press <kbd>Ctrl-2</kbd>, then <kbd>L</kbd> for "assign to local variable".

Comment: Awesome, that's sufficient for me!

Comment: Or Alt-Shift-L (win) or Command-Option-L (mac), for *Refactor>Extract Local Variable*.